# Generate database schema from NHibernate mapping

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, code-generation

Is it possible to generate the database schema from the Nhibernate mappings DLL?

My requirements is for MySQL.
If so, how do I do that? Are there tools/scripts for this? Open source/freeware tools?
Additionally, can I use these tools to insert/update datasets to the database?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried using [NHibernate's built-in schema generation tool](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide)?

```
var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
cfg.Configure();
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(AnEntityInYourMappingLib).Assembly);
new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code :

```
public void CreateDatabaseSchemaFromMappingFiles()
{
    NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
    cfg.Configure();
    NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport schema = new NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport(cfg);
    schema.Create(false, true);
}
```